# PAMGuard not reading files

Tags: pamguard, recording, files

PAMguard is leaving quite a lot of files unproccesed. They are all in the same folder, but apparently it cannot access to some of them (image 1), and it appears to be in a random manner (image 2). We have been proccessing them directly as .sud  since the last PAMguard version.

We tried unzipping the problematic files into .wav and opened it in Audacity, and they can be heard with no problem. We also re-run the folder in PAMGuard in smaller datasets (2 weeks); and lastly, we tried proccesing them as .vaw, and re-run only 2 days worth of data, but also it did not work. So far, we have only been able to proccess them if we select one by one (which is not very comfortable for the long-term)

In case anybody is familiar with this situation, or has any idea how to get PAMguard to access the  files would really appreciate! Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you reduce the number of files such that only 1 or 2  of the socalled 'corrupt' files are present (given by the hole in the longer sequence)? Is alway the same file not readable or does it vary?

Comment: It appears to be the same files always. We have realised there are several recordings of only 1KB from this deployment, and it cannot read those ones (of course), but also does not read the following 'normal' recording right after those. If i select only these ones -without the 1kb files- it can proccess them without any problem.

Comment: OK, it seems to be the files them self as you suggested in OP. Can you decode the files with Soundtrap-Host program, or with the soundtrap reader? Your OP is not clear in that sense (AFAIK, there is no zip format involved)

Comment: Would it be workable to sort your files by size, pull all those 1 kb 'bad' files into a 'bad files' folder, and then only process the 'normal' files all in one go? Or does it still get stuck on the offending files even without the 1 kb bad file before it?

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your comments. And my apologies, i am quite new to this and I am not sure what OP means (Original Poster?). Anyhow, I did as Selene suggested and it worked! I could extract with Soundtrap-Host (except for the 1KB files). But I also proccessed them in .sud format and it was good :) It seemed that the 1KB files were  preventeding PAMguard in some way from continuing processing the next files after those. Next step will be figuring out why the soundtrap recorded so many 1kb files (...but that's a story for another day). Thank you!

Comment: mabe you could post one 1kb sud file, so one can look into it with hexeditor?

Comment: I believe Stack Exchange does not allow to upload files, but maybe this works: https://we.tl/t-gVzeuqZ8vW

Comment: One possible reason you are getting so many 1kb files is that there may have been offloading errors. What model soundtrap are you using? Do you still have the data on the recorder? I have had several occasions where some files randomly failed to offload. If you look at the 'File Listing' window in the soundtrap host software you can  see the size of the files. Check to make sure none of those sizes are 1kb. If they all look good on the host software try redownloading those files.

Comment: So it was exactly that Kourtney. We are using ST300HF. We have re-downloaded the 1kb files manually (from Soundtrap Host 3.5.0.27712) and it is all good. Thank you very much!